# How to retrieve the Value of KeyValuePair from database in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I am working on a project involving KeyValuePair. I have int as key, and string as Value.

What I want is I want to get the Value from KeyValuePair.

I have this code:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()
{
  new KeyValuePair<int, string>(obj,_Obj.Questions)
            };

Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
      { 1, "Welcome, How are you?" },
      { 2, "Tell me something about yourself."},
      { 3, "How much experience do you have?"},
};
```

So if you see the string Values in KVP like "Welcome, How are you?", "Tell me something about yourself" etc is a static one. All these values are already present in my local database. I want these string values from database only.

I am using **MS SQL Database**

Is this possible??

Comment: d[1] will give you value from KVP for 1

Comment: Not fully sure if I am understanding since you mentioned a database. But if you want the value from a key value pair, you would use the .Value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2.value?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair_2_Value. If you are trying to get each value from the dictionary you can loop the dictionary and access the .Value of each item.

Comment: How is the KeyValuePair stored in Db ? Could you share how your table looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any ORM like Entity Framework, however, I will provide an example to do it manually :

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()

using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM interview_Table", connection))
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) { connection.Open(); }

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        foreach (var row in reader)
        {
            //ensurance
            var isValidId = int.TryParse(row["Id"]?.ToString(), int out id);

            var description = row["Description"]?.ToString();       

            // only fetch rows with a valid id number with description that is not empty or null
            if(isValidId && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
            {
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(id, description));
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used DataRow instead of var row in foreach loop. But it is giving me error saying "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.Data.DataRow' "

Comment: @RohanRao `reader` returns `DbDataRecord`, which has no inheritance with `DataRow`. So, it's impossible to cast it to `DataRow` out of the box!. That's why you received that error when you changed `var` to `DataRow`. To solve it you'll need to find a work around, like loading the reader via `DataTable` then convert it to DataRow, (e.g. `DataTable.Load(reader)`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are asking is possible.

You'll have to establish a database connection and run a query to pull the data needed. Once the data is received take it and put it into a collection.

This collection could contain KeyValuePairs like you have written **or** you could create a class that replicates the table structure and have a collection of those objects.

You could also go a step further and look into something such as Entity Framework.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **EntityFramework** `ToDictionary` function to do this mapping.

```
var test = await this.dbcontext.InterviewQuestions
    .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Description})
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToDictionaryAsync(xkvp  => xkvp.Id, xkvp.Description);
```

1. You can check [getting started with EF core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli) if you are using .net core
2. You can check [getting started with EF 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/get-started) if you are using .net

One of my personal favorites [code first with EF 6 from existing DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database) will generate most of the code you need.

Comment: Thanks :) I am getting an error - The second parameter should be cancellationToken instead of x.Description.

Comment: Try with the updated version. `ToDictionaryAsync` will only map the `InterviewQuestion` object to a key value, so you can only provide the key and a cancellation token for the async part.